# finding implicit representation of plane

Tags: math, graphics, 2d, point, plane

I have 2 questions:

1. How can I find the implicit representation of a plane that passes through the point: (6,1,0), if it is given that the plane is parallel to a line that lies on the yz-plane
2. Can we determine how many possible solutions exists?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question.  It is more appropriate for https://math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The yz-plane has a simple basis, namely, {(0,1,0), (0,0,1)}. Take a point p in the plane you are looking for. Then p - (6,1,0) must lie on the yz-plane, i.e. it must be a linear combination of the basis. Therefore,

```
p - (6,1,0) = λ(0,1,0) + μ(0,0,1)
```

or

```
p = λ(0,1,0) + μ(0,0,1) + (6,1,0)
```

where λ and μ are the parameters.

Note that the representation is not unique because it depends on the basis chosen for the yz-plane. A different basis would require different values for the parameters.

Comment: Thank you!
and is it correct so say that there is infinity number of solutions(for finding this implicit representation)?